# v-for и списки в Vue

Tags: vue.js, фреймворк

В процессе изучения документации Vue наткнулся на такой пример:

html:

```
<div id="app-4">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-4',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: 'Изучить JavaScript' },
      { text: 'Изучить Vue' },
      { text: 'Создать что-нибудь классное' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Каким образом берется `todo` в `todos` если в коде его нет (а тем более это массив)?

Comment: `todo` это **элемент** из `todos`

Comment: Откуда берется это название если в коде его нет?

Comment: vue разбирает строку `v-for="todo in todos"` и создает все необходимые локальные переменные. Подробнее можно посмотреть в исходниках

Comment: Допустим там вместо `todos` будет `name` то что будет вместо `todo`?

Comment: `name` - нигде не объявленная переменная, поэтому будет просто ошибка. `todos` - объявлена в `data`. `todo` - локальная переменная. которая может иметь любое имя.

Comment: Твой вопрос аналогичен следующему: `for(var todo of todos){...}` каким образом берется `todo`